# why the active tabs was undefined when send message from backend to content script in google chrome extension v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vuejs3, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am tried to send message from background in google chrome extension v3, this is the background message send code looks like:

```
export function sendMessageToContent(message: MessageBase) {
    debugger
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        if(activeTab && activeTab.id !== undefined){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
        }
    });
}
```

when I get the current active tab, the tabs was return undefined, why did this happen? I am sure there contains active tabs in google chrome broswer, what should I do to fix this problem? This is the debug view:

[image]

Comment: It's because your active window is devtools. Remove `debugger` from your code and set breakpoints normally so that the code runs when the actual browser window is active.

Comment: is it possible to let google chrome get the active window when debuging? @wOxxOm

Comment: did you know why did not work in debug mode@wOxxOm

Comment: chrome.windows.getCurrent({populate: true}, w => { var tab = w.tabs.find(t => t.active); })